# libx264 performances on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, h.264, x264

I was wondering whether someone has some experience using libx264 on iPhone.

How does it perform? What framerate can I expect? Will it work for simultaneous encoding & decoding (video call) or the CPU can't handle it? I'm mainly interested with iPhone 4 and above (iPhone4/iPad 2)

Are there any precompiled universal binaries I can use?

Comment: After trying it myself, I can answer my own question:

I was surprised by the performances of the codec. I was able to get very good performances out of it on both iPad2/iPhone4. iPhone4 can get easily to 10fps while iPad2 can get 15fps. At the same time, both devices also decode H264 (using ffmpeg) plus encode/decode audio.

Comment: Your results would be much more useful if you specified what Resolution and settings you used.